# Complex SQL query to JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have 3 Tables : **Organization**, **Vehicle** and **VehicleStatus**.

Organization (one To Many) with Vehicle. (an organization can have many Vehicles).
 Vehicle (one To Many) with VehicleStatus (a vehicle has different status that we store whenever the status changes, VehicleStatus has a statusDate column to store when the status change was done).

I would like to get the vehicles which statusType (column) has BROKEN  and that belong to Organizations that are located in NewYork.

**VehicleStatus (id, statusType, statusDate, Vehicle)
Vehicle(id, organization)
Organization (id, city)**

This is the SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM Vehicles V, VehicleStatus VS, Organization O
where (V.id = VS.Vehicle) AND (V.organisation = O.id)
and (O.city = "Bordeaux")
and (VS.statusType = "Broken")
and (VS.statusDate == (select Max(statusDate) from VehicleStatus groupBy vehicle where vehicle = V.id);
```

how can I convert it in JPQL?

thanks

Comment: You should try something at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve this with the 

In Vehicle entity  you should have the relation as like 

@ManytoOne
@joinColumns(name="organization_id" , insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Organization organization;

and in you should have the  relationship to the  VehicleStatus entity as below in Vehicle entity

@OneToMany
private List<VehicleStatus> vehicleStatuses;
```

and your query should be like this

```
List<Vehicle> Vehicles=createQuery("select new Vehicle(required column list )  from  Vehicle v left join v.organization o  left join v.vehicleStatuses vs where  vs.status=?1 and o.organizationId=?2")
.setparameter(1,status)
.setParameter(2,organizationId)
.getResultList();
```

Comment: the problem is that i need to select statuses that have the max statusDate (last update of the status)